# Installing react-native-testing-library gives react peer dependency error when I have a compatible react version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-testing-library

[image]

I get this error when I try to install react-native-testing-library (using expo for my project), which tells me I need react@>=16.8.0, but I have react@18.1.0, so shouldn't this be fine? Am I misunderstanding the error message?

Answer (score 0):

That should indeed be fine. Is this the whole error log?
I am using versions:

```
"@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

They work well together, you can try those. If it still doesn't work, please post the complete error log and your whole package.json. That makes it easier to find which dependencies are actually conflicting